# Creating a color inputtype through Htmlhelper.editorfor() (MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, html-helper

I have the following part of a form created using htmlhelper:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ColorCode, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ColorCode, new {htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            <!--<input type="color" class="form-control"/>-->
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ColorCode, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
        </div>
    </div>
```

The datatype of `ColorCode` is string, so by default it just creates a normal textbox. What I want is to have the input behave as a color selector. The commented html is essentially what I want it to create (+ whatever attributes are needed to connect it to the form, if applicable. I'm not a HTML expert). Is there a way to do this? I can't find any information on it through my searches.

Comment: `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ColorCode, new { @class = "form-control", type="color" })`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ColorCode, new {@class="form-control", type="color"})
```

The `EditorFor` will use Editor Templates to generate the html output. To use that you have to define an Editor template for that particular property type, but since that's a `string` it's a bit generic.

Also @Stephen Muecke pointed it out in the comment.

Comment: This works fine. My initial solution I tried and failed with also worked, actually. But I like yours more since with it I can keep using the `@Html.`-format. The problem was actually that I had changed the type of my colorcode from an int to a string on the backend (to make handling the input from the colorpicker's type easier), but I had forgotten to update a part of my API to build it as a string instead of an int. Regardless, thanks!